# Password encryption and decryption in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, passwords

How can I encrypt and decrypt a password in Google app engine without using third party libraries?

Any examples?

Comment: The obvious answer is "write your own". Which is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you care about your users' security, you're going to have to use a third-party library of some sort, because the *only* way you should be storing passwords is securely hashed with PBKDF2, SCrypt, or BCrypt - for instance, using [this module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbkdf2/1.3), which you can easily add to your application.

Note that you should *never* encrypt passwords (and thus, never decrypt them) - instead, algorithms like PBKDF2 use hashing so that you can check if a password is valid, but never recover the original password.

Comment: An MD5 hash is also fine for a password hash, assuming you use a salt.  It is also easier to implement.

Comment: @Michael No, it's not - a salted hash is far too insecure. You should _always_ use a password hashing scheme like PBKDF2, SCrypt or BCrypt when storing user passwords.

Comment: After some research I agree that MD5 is not a good choice; although, I argue that your statment of a salted MD5 hash is "far too insecure".  I couldn't find any record of a salted MD5 hash attack that was successful.  LinkedIn had a problem with their unsalted MD5 hash at one point.  If you keep the salt (or have better yet have two salts, one applied on the client and one applied on the server to the first hash) this would be alleviated.  The advantage the other hashes have is they require more computation (and have the ability to continue requiring more computation over time).

Comment: How successful an attack against salted passwords is depends on how good the original password was, but it's entirely practical for someone with modest resources to target individual salted password hashes using a reasonable dictionary; using a proper hashing scheme like PBKDF2 massively increases the work required to do this.