# ImportError: No module named PBKDF2

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Trying to implement password encryption and decryption in python on google app engine. Made some research and from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227509/password-encryption-and-decryption-in-google-app-engine) i learned of PBKDF2 . i have installed the module using `pip install pbkdf2` and have downloaded the entire package as illustrated [here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/) and [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbkdf2/1.3). Still when importing the module as `from PBKDF2 import PBKDF2` , i still get `ImportError: No module named PBKDF2` is there anything i am missing and how do i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PBKDF2 documentation seems to be wrong, you need to refer to the module in lowercase:

```
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2
```

A more general tip, if you're working with pip it's useful to remember this command:

`pip show -f <package>`

This will list all the files installed by a package and their base location. It's specially useful when dealing with packages that include command line tools or compiled extensions.